# Where can I see the amount of time people are spending in my app?

Tags: facebook-analytics

I saw the tool has median session length, but does it allow me to see total time spent per user?

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is possible, if you go to the active users section e.g. https://www.facebook.com/analytics/**your-app-id**/?section=active_users. You can click the carrot next to "Median Session Length" and change to "Median Time Spent per User"

[Facebook Analytics for Apps Time Spent Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7v1a.png)